# subscripted letters in UITextField placeholder

Tags: iphone, ipad, subscript

I need to learn about ways of doing this.  The options I am aware of are:

1)  Load my own custom font which includes subscripted letters, or

2)  Simulate a "placeholder" with two UILabels positioned directly over the UITextField, and make those labels go away when the user starts typing.  In my case, this will be more work than it sounds like, because the whole thing will need to be data-driven.

Are there other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As best I can tell, the answer is "no".